# why doesnt my code work, learning python

Tags: python, string, list, function

I am learning python on codecademy. It is going okay so far, however I cannot understand why my code works one way and not a different way. So here is the code I have made:

```
n = ["Michael", "Lieberman"]

def join_strings(words):

    result = ""

    for i in range(len(words)):

        result += i

    return result 

print join_strings(n)
```

## this code doesn't work... below is the code that is working for me...............

```
n = ["Michael", "Lieberman"]

def join_strings(words):

    result = ""

    for i in range(len(words)):

        result += words[i]

    return result 


print join_strings(n)
```

my question is more regarding confusion on "words[i]", and what makes that code work vs the way I did it? thanks

Comment: `I` doesn't exist in the first block. However, if you meant `i` then it's just an incrementing integer (which you can't concatenate with a string), while in the second case you use that integer as an index.

Comment: sorry I have corrected "I' to 'i'. I did not know that "I" could be used as an integer... how does "i" work as an index. sorry for noob question

Comment: See [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_lists.htm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first you are adding up the integer you loop over

```
n = ["Michael", "Lieberman"]

for i in range(len(n)):

    result += i # i = 0 then i = 1, sum up to 1
    print i # add this to see what you are adding up to your list

return result
```

Now, if you write:

```
n[0]
```

It will return the first element in your list `n = ["Michael", "Lieberman"]`, then the code:

```
n = ["Michael", "Lieberman"]

for i in range(len(n)):

    result += n[i]

return result
```

shall return the concatenation of what is in the list versus adding up the integer you loop over in the first code.

Answer (score 0):

`i` will be an integer, not the word in `word[]` as this is what `range()` returns. `len(words)` also returns an integer which is the `length` or count of the words array.

You get access to the word by passing the index of the array in to `word[]` starting from `0` eg `word[0]` will be the first element of the array, `word[1]` will be the second.

Details about range():
http://pythoncentral.io/pythons-range-function-explained/

Details about len():
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/list_len.htm

Comment: sort of bums me out that people down-vote my question when I am just learning

Comment: Try to be more specific with you question, try to describe the issue as well as you can. Often that alone will help you to determine the problem. It will also help you to see if it is a duplicate question.